# android - textView textColor not taking effect on device

Tags: android

I have a layout like this. Here I set the textColor to red.

When I run this on emulator, everything works as expected. However, when I run on device, textColor is white. It used to work on device.

I did lot of code refactoring with emulator. I might have changed something that could lead to this issue. I was hoping if someone else has encountered a similar issue.

```
        <TextView
            android:layout_width="wrap_content"
            android:layout_height="wrap_content"
            android:text="EXAMPLE"
            android:textColor="@color/red"
            android:textSize="60sp" />
```

What could be the issue?

```
android {
    dexOptions {
        javaMaxHeapSize "6g"
    }
    compileSdkVersion 23
    buildToolsVersion "23.0.2"
    packagingOptions {
        exclude 'META-INF/DEPENDENCIES'
    }
    defaultConfig {
        applicationId "someID"
        minSdkVersion 15
        targetSdkVersion 23
        versionCode 1
        versionName "1.0"
        multiDexEnabled true
    }
    productFlavors {
        dev {
            minSdkVersion 15
        }
        prod {
            minSdkVersion 15
        }
    }
    buildTypes {
        release {
            minifyEnabled true
            proguardFiles getDefaultProguardFile('proguard-android.txt'), 'proguard-rules.pro'
        }
    }
    compileOptions {
        sourceCompatibility JavaVersion.VERSION_1_7
        targetCompatibility JavaVersion.VERSION_1_7
    }
}
```

Comment: What versions of Android are running on both device and emulator? This could occur if you have different layout xml files for different Android API. If physical device and emulator are running different API levels than maybe the TextView in the xml layout that targets that specific Android version is not set correctly, while the layout loaded in the emulator is written as you described.

Comment: My emulator is Android 6.0 api 23. I have a GalaxyS6 as device which may not be api 23 as its android 5.x. I updated the post with my gradle config. Please provide pointers to fix this.

Comment: Is the TextView in an xml layout file of which you have multiple versions? See this [screenshot](http://imgur.com/MjklfaB) to see what I'm talking about.

Comment: There doesn't seem to be any traceable problem. Try to clean the project and the rebuild it.

Answer (score 1):

I resolved this issue by cleaning all build directories and clean/rebuild.

I also removed productflavors/devDebug from .gradle. That must have caused the issue as I was it was configured for minSDKVersion 15 and I was trying to run on 22.

From Android docs:

```
android {
    productFlavors {
        // Define separate dev and prod product flavors.
        dev {
            // dev utilizes minSDKVersion = 21 to allow the Android gradle plugin
            // to pre-dex each module and produce an APK that can be tested on
            // Android Lollipop without time consuming dex merging processes.
            minSdkVersion 21
        }
        prod {
            // The actual minSdkVersion for the application.
            minSdkVersion 14
        }
    }
          ...
    buildTypes {
        release {
            runProguard true
            proguardFiles getDefaultProguardFile('proguard-android.txt'),
                                                 'proguard-rules.pro'
        }
    }
}
```